# Get custom attribute value from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clone a select options into another select. At the moment I'm able to do it but now the original option contains a custom attribute. So my question is how can I access to the custom attribute? This is what I have for now:

```
var options = $('#sel1 option');
var arrayOptions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var id = parseInt($(options[i]).val(), 10);
    var text = $(options[i]).text() || '[select a type]';
            
    arrayOptions.push('<option value="' + id + ' data-custom="' + options[i]["data-custom"] + '">' + text + '</option>');
    
}
console.log(arrayOptions);

<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1" data-custom="abc1">Hello 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-custom="abc2">Hello 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-custom="abc3">Hello 3</option>
</select>
```

Right now options[i]["data-custom"] is setting undefined instead of abc1, abc2, etc.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/crago2sf/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dataset.custom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
var options = $('#sel1 option');
var arrayOptions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var id = parseInt($(options[i]).val(), 10);
    var text = $(options[i]).text() || '[select a type]';
                
    arrayOptions.push('<option value="' + id + ' data-custom="' + options[i].dataset.custom + '">' + text + '</option>');
}
$('#result').text(arrayOptions.join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1">
<option value="1" data-custom="abc1">Hello 1</option>
<option value="2" data-custom="abc2">Hello 2</option>
<option value="3" data-custom="abc3">Hello 3</option>
</select>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const arrayOptions = 
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#sel1 option')]
  .map( opt => `<option value="${opt.id}" `
             + `data-custom"${opt.dataset.custom}">`
             + `${opt.textContent}"</option>`
      )
console.log(arrayOptions);
```

```html
 <select id="sel1">
  <option value="1" data-custom="abc1">Hello 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-custom="abc2">Hello 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-custom="abc3">Hello 3</option>
</select>
```